# start kettle in ubuntu error

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

When I want to start Kettle:

$ cd ../kettle/data-integration
$ spoon.sh

there is a error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Check this one :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903657/error-running-spoon-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue many times when i change the kettle directory or execute it from different path . The solution that worked for me is to remove the extracted folder and extract a fresh copy and the system starts working.Beside this also check that you are using Oracle java instead of open java comes with ubuntu.